# When do I get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

Tags: java, ssl, axis, jsse

I implemented trust store using `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`. In my client (which uses axis to talk to server), I am getting the following error when calling `connectSocket()`. In which cases I get this error?

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate
>   found

Answer (score 0):

You get that exception when the RootCA, the Intermediate-CA or the whole CA-chain is missing. This post might help you solve your problem: [SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394361/ignore-ssl-certificate-in-a-servlet/33596697#33596697)